# How to overwrite another view when UITableView scrolls

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` and another view on my view. When my `tableView` scrolls. How to override the view below

[image]

the clockImageView‘s superView is `UITableView`。The `blueView` is another view。
I used an automatic layout. The tableView has a fixed height。Another view is close to the tableView。
can do it when I scroll the `tableView`. Cover `blueView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Move blue view on top of tableView
   [image]
2. Layout your blue view's bottom equal to tableView's bottom
3. tableView's background color is clear

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I scroll my TableView. It is still the case.
I updated my constraints in the problem description.

Comment: Sorry, I may not understand your bottom constraint. How can I layout your blue view's bottom equal to tableView's bottom。because the Blue View.top = Table View.bottom。

Comment: Just a trick: change Blue View.top into Blue View.bottom. Blue view will be behind tableView, but you still can see blue view because tableView's background color is clear. So when your cell is dragged it'll override blue view.

Comment: Hahaha I tried Blue View.top = Table View.bottom
But the constraint is wrong. . . I may still be stupid. Can you show your constraints?